# Ingeniería inversa: Concatenar/Encadenar métodos de una clase

Tags: php, php7

he visto que algunos métodos de en una misma clases se pueden concatenar/encadenar, por ejemplo:

```php
(new ClassFoo())
->foo1()
->foo2();
```

mi pregunta es inversa.... ***como debe ser la estructura de una clase para lograr esta concatenación ???***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta extraída de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724136/3613462

```
<?php
class fakeString
{
    private $str;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->str = "";
    }
    
    function addA()
    {
        $this->str .= "a";
        return $this;
    }
    
    function addB()
    {
        $this->str .= "b";
        return $this;
    }
    
    function getStr()
    {
        return $this->str;
    }
}


$a = new fakeString();


echo $a->addA()->addB()->getStr();
```

Salida:
"ab"

Lectura sugerida: https://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/method-chaining-php