# ¿Como ecadenar un metodo mágico en uno estático?

Tags: php, php7, patrones-de-diseño

Me encuentro actualmente desarrollando en laravel y una de las cosas que he visto al momento de usar eloquent es el encadenamiento que realizan con otros metodos
ejemplo

```
$table = Table::all()->where('name','Alex');
```

¿Cómo es posible que el método que es magico sea encadenado con un metodo estático?
He visto el patrón CoR (Chain of Responsibility) y hasta ahora solo he visto que lo hacen con métodos mágicos

Comment: no son metodos magicos

Comment: y no esta relacionado unicamente a laravel lo puedes hacer en cualquier framework php que implemente loader etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que tener todo armado con su namespace y el metodo en teoria tiene que retornar `self::${innstancia_de_la_clase}` te dejo una explicacion de como se hace:

Primero necesitas una clase cualquier en la cual declaras *una propiedad statica privada* y a su vez un *metodo publico estatico* que valida y retorna la instancia y `self`:

```
<?php

class FooClass
{

    private static ?FooClass $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance(): FooClass
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    public function fooMethod(string $text){
        echo $text;
    }
}
```

De esta forma al ejecutar: `FooClass::` tu loader resuelve el acceso a la clase pero al ejecutar `getInstance()` estas retornando la instancia; como estas retornando la instancia te permite acceder directamente a un metodo chain que le siga y que self tenga acceso, por ejemplo `fooMethod()` en este caso quedaria asi la llamada:

```php
FooClass::getInstance()->fooMethod("Hello World!")
```

el output:

> Hello World!

Tambien lo aprendi a hacer hace poco, pero con metodos normales:

[Documentacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/541713/46896)

A lo mejor puede haber otra forma más elegante pero para mi fue la mejor y facil de entender.

---

Para mi concepto no son metodo magicos cuando se hacen cadenas con static; para mi un metodo magico seria algo como:

```php
$Class = 'FooClass';
$getInstance = 'getInstance';
$metodoCallback = 'fooMethod';

$Class::$getInstance()->$metodoCallback("Hello World!")
```

Cuando estas sustitullendo las partes de un codigo por variables dinamicas, esto tiene sus problemas con los IDE y es que pierden la trasabilidad ... no es recomendado... Evitalo...